# Debug : cannot see how a function is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

EDIT : when I jump to the definition of the function "connection", it brings me to NSURLRequest header. And as there is a NSUrlRequest in createLoginCheck, "connection" is certainly the implementation in the code. Confirm you later ;)

I have an iPhone application to improve. This application connects to an ipCamera and displays the video stream with a UIImageView. This is for the concept. My problem is that I have to ensure this application works with another type of camera. So I tried to understand how the code worked, and at a moment I cannot trace the code anymore. This seems magic for me (I precise I'm new with Objective C).

How does it happen ? I connect to the ipcam with a login form. When I click on the login button, if the connection is established, I arrive on a view displaying the video stream (if the ipcam is connected but the video stream not managed, I anyway connect to the cam and display the view, but there is no video : it displays nothing, because the function downloads an empty informations, but downloads them). The display view is not shown only if I cannot connect to the ipcam, otherwise it displays an error message and stays on the login view.

So I have put a breakpoint on the IBAction linked to the login button and harassed "step INTO" to see what happened after I clicked the login button. But what happens in the debugger is the following : steps throught the IBAction and after the function done seems to access framework methods like

```
_UIApplicationHandleEvent
-[UIApplication sendEvent:]
-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:]
-[UIControl(internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
...
```

And after everything has been executed, the program executes normally and goes to the next view displaying the video. Maybe my debugging methods are not optimum. Here is my code :

IBAction linked to the login button, after IP and port field have been filled in :

```
//IPCamera Login Button clicked
-(IBAction)IPCameraLoginClick:(id)sender //Breakpoint here
{   
    NSLog(@"IPCameraLoginClick");
    if(VPONAutoSave)
        [self saveVPONLoginInfo];
    [self createLoginCheck];
}//breakpoint stops here before loading the next view
```

I've put a breakpoint to the method createLoginCheck but it still stops at the end of IPCameraLoginClick. Normal ^^

```
-(void)createLoginCheck
{
    NSLog(@"createLoginCheck");
    bShowConnectionFail = YES;
    NSURLRequest *theRequest5;
    if(baseMode == VPONVIEW)
    {
        theRequest5=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://%@:%@/",VPONIP.text,VPONPort.text]]
                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                 timeoutInterval:10.0];

    }
    else
    {
        theRequest5=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://%@:%@/",IPCameraIP.text,IPCameraPort.text]]
                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                 timeoutInterval:10.0];
    }       

    theConnection5=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest5 delegate:self];
    if (theConnection5) 
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection5");
    } 
    else 
    {       
        NSLog(@"no connect");
        [self createConnectionFail];
    }   
}
```

And where I get back the datas :

```
//===receive data from server===
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{    
    NSLog(@"Raw Datas : %@", data);

    if(connection == theConnection1)
    {
        [data getBytes:(void *)(buffer1+len1) length:[data length]];
        len1 += [data length];
    }
    else if(connection == theConnection2)
    {
        [data getBytes:(void *)(buffer2+len2) length:[data length]];
        len2 += [data length];
    }
        //Blablabla
    else if(connection == theConnection8)
    {
        NSLog(@"CONNECTION 8 ENGAGED ");
        [data getBytes:(void *)(buffer8+len8) length:[data length]];
        len8 += [data length];
        NSLog(@"Lenght 8 : %d", len8);
        //NSLog(@"Lenght 8 : %@", data);
    }

    NSLog(@"didReceiveData");   
}
```

So briefly, what I want to do is to understand how I can pass from the end of the IBAction to the connection function. I've looked in the code but couldn't find where the function was called. I have 4 classes (2 .m and 2.h). An appDelegate with a douzain of lines, and a controller for all the views in the program (about 2400 lines :/ ). And the main contains 10 lines maximum. So maybe this has to be dealed with the .ib, but I don't understand so much how it works.

Comment: The method connection:didReceiveData is called by the NSURLConnection like you must have figured out. It is implemented in your code to indicate the length of the received data, see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

Comment: Hey thanks. I had a quick look, that's interesting !